# Matrix Multiplication Problem

Tags: matrices

I'm working on the following problem and I can't seem to come up with the right answer. 
$$ \text{Let}:  A^{-1} =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 1 \\
        0 & 3 & 1 \\
        4 & 1 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
Find a matrix such that:

$$ ACA = 
\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 1 & 3 \\
        -1 & 2 & 2 \\
        2 & 1 & 4 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: Your computation is wrong. You cannot just replace $AC$ with $(AC)^{-1}$.

Comment: I don't see any instances of that in my question

Comment: oh nevermind now I do.

Comment: It is exactly what you did in your second equality: you wrote $ACA=(C^{-1}A^{-1})A$. Not true with the exception of some very particular choices of $A$ and $C$.

Comment: Ok, I see. Removed.

Comment: If you use `bmatrix` instead of `matrix`, you get the square brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$ B = 
\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 1 & 3 \\
        -1 & 2 & 2 \\
        2 & 1 & 4 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

$ACA = B$ if and only if $A^{-1}ACA = A^{-1}B$ if and only if $A^{-1}ACAA^{-1} = A^{-1}BA^{-1}$. Now, multiplication between matrices is not commutative but it is associative! Hence you have:
$$A^{-1}ACAA^{-1} = (A^{-1}A)C(AA^{-1}) = C$$

Then to find such a matrix $C$ you just need to calculate $A^{-1}BA^{-1}$, which is something you can do explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
C=A^{-1}(ACA)A^{-1}.
$$
So
$$
C=  \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 1 \\
        0 & 3 & 1 \\
        4 & 1 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\,\cdot\,
\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 1 & 3 \\
        -1 & 2 & 2 \\
        2 & 1 & 4 \\
        \end{bmatrix}\,\cdot\,
\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 1 \\
        0 & 3 & 1 \\
        4 & 1 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now you can just perform the computation.